# Load images after the timer is done

Tags: image, timer, blogger

Is there anyway to show an image just after the time.

Like you need to wait 10 seconds before the image will show on Blogger,com

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Here's draft example

```
<img id="myImg" src="whatever.png" style="display: none;">
```

Javascript:

```
var count = 10;
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    count--;    

    if(count == 0) {
        document.querySelector('myImg').style.display = 'block';
        return clearInterval(timer);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Well, I assumed that before you asked you tried to do the task by yourself, but got difficulty. No one will do your work for you here.